# Crystal Sum with two conditions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to get summary by two conditions, much like Sumifs function of excel
Like - Sum(Total_Costs) where Region = 4 and Currency = USD. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to create a Formula called @Region4USD

Something like

```
if ({YourReport.Region} = 4 and {YourReport.Curency} = "USD") then
    {YourReport.Total_Cost}
else
    0
```

Then create a SUM on the formula

Answer (score 2):

You can create a running total.  That way, you have the option of using the "Evaluate" section to use your own conditions when you click on the "Use formula" option.