# Crystal Sum on field value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How do I sum a specific field based on values in some other column. I am trying to do - Sum of Annual Costs (Column to be summarized) where Cost type (Column field the summary is to be based upon) = Equipment Costs.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly identical to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4337759/334849); create a formula that does the following:

```
if ({YourReport.CostType} = "Equipment Costs") then 
    {YourReport.AnnualCosts} 
else 
    0
```

And then create a summary on this formula.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention this part - Also, some of the costs I mentioned below have more than one components , like Labor cost includes Internal Labor Costs, External Labor costs, Benefits. Labor Cost = Internal LC + External LC + Benefits. So how do I create a formula for such a situation? Do I create If statement formula for each one and then add them in a different formula or is there a better way of doing it? Thanks again